# Set a link in child theme style.css to jump to #main

Tags: child-theme, css, theme-twenty-thirteen

I have created a 2013 child theme by creating these 2 files -

**/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child/style.css**:

```
@import url("../twentythirteen/style.css");

.site-header .home-link {
    min-height: 800px;
}
```

**/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child/functions.php**:

```
<?php

function my_custom_header_setup() {
        $args = array('height' => 800);
        add_theme_support('custom-header', $args);
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'my_custom_header_setup');

?>
```

Now the website has a large image at the top and looks as I wanted it.

However, when users click at the large image, then "nothing happens" for them.

I would like to change it, so that the click at the large image causes scroll down to the **#main** anchor:

[image: website bukvy.de]

Is such a change please possible through the **style.css**? I have searched and couldn't find a CSS solution (or hack) for that.

If not, then how to achieve this in the most simple way? (I am trying to keep the child theme small for easier site updates).

My *workaround* for now is to [disable the link with CSS](https://css-tricks.com/pointer-events-current-nav/), but I am still interested in a better solution:

```
.site-header .home-link {
       pointer-events: none;
       cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: You are just searching for an onpage anchor. Simply add a link with `#id-of-target` as `href`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is **NO, You can not!** CSS stand for `Cascade Style Sheet` which mean to style elements in cascade order. CSS can not change the DOM.

There are two ways to achieve it.

1. Overriding `header.php`
2. Using JavaScript or jQuery **(Not recommended)**

**Method 1:** Copy the `header.php` to your child theme and modify `href` link with what you want!
Example:

```
<a class="home-link" href="#main" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
    <h1 class="site-title"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h1>
    <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
</a>
```

**Method 2:** Personally I will not recommend it. It is better to have less js as much as possible. If you want to go with this solution you can ask this to [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/)